# django-easy_pdf display pdf number

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am using [django-easy_pdf](https://django-easy-pdf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to reder pdf for my reports and would like to know how to display a page footer.

In the [django-easy_pdf](https://django-easy-pdf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)'s source code this piece of code is used to display the page number

```
<div id="footerContent">
    {%block page_foot%}
        <pdf:pagenumber />
    {%endblock%}
</div>
```

What I would like to know is:

- How to display the footer properly
- Start with page number 1

As I have copied the code, it does not display as a footer and the page starts with 0

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

I tried this code from [here](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/571) but I can't make it work, seems useful though

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .footer { position: fixed; bottom: 0px; }
            .pagenum:before { content: counter(page); }
        </style>
    </head>

        <body>
            <div class="footer">Page: <span class="pagenum"></span></div>
       </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE 2**

I now know what I did wrong, I was missing the `@page` css and that is why It's not working, I only have the `@frame footer`

The correct CSS:

```
 @page {
     size: {{ pagesize }};
     margin: 1cm;
     @frame footer {
         -pdf-frame-content: footerContent;
         bottom: 0cm;
         margin-left: 18cm;
         margin-right: 0cm;
         height: 1cm;
    }
}
```

Then just call it normally(the first snippet)

Comment: Can you paste a template code that you try to render? Code from your view should also be helpful.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to do that?

Comment: Maybe you could help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display footer correctly make sure that in your template in css styles you have:

```
@frame footer {
     -pdf-frame-content: footerContent;
}
```

-pdf-frame-content should be pointig to id of your footer container.

Comment: This is exactly what I did, my problem is how can I make it stick to the buttom of the pdf and make it start with 1 instead of 0

Answer (score 0):

You can add the next code in your tempate:

```
{%block page_foot%}
  <div style="display: block;margin: 0 auto;text-align: center;">
    page: <pdf:pagenumber />
  </div>
{%endblock%}
```